# Error loading Xml-Serialized DataTable user-scoped setting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datatable, xml-serialization

Out of nowhere, I'm getting the following error in my Winforms VB.NET 4.5 application (Visual Studio 2013) on the project/main form load:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.XmlSerializers,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Viewing the details, its HResult # is `-2147024894` coming from `mscorlib`.  It's happening in this part of the application user-settings' application-created code in `Settings.vb`:

```
<Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
 Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
Public Property dt_ColumnProperties() As Global.System.Data.DataTable
    Get
        ' error occurs in this line:
        Return CType(Me("dt_ColumnProperties"),Global.System.Data.DataTable)
    End Get
    Set
        Me("dt_ColumnProperties") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The result is that the `DataTable`'s values are not read (which is a major problem).  Apparently, it doesn't believe that `XmlSerialization` can happen with a `DataTable`?  Or maybe it forgets how to do it somehow.  I don't know what might have changed, and it has been working previously for months.

I've tried deleting the `dt_ColumnProperties` user-setting and re-creating it, but that did not solve the issue.  I also found [this post's solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/46e94d1e-4454-4c09-a073-d175444f8f10/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mscorlibxmlserializers-version4000-cultureneutral?forum=windowsazuredevelopment&prof=required) to the same error, but I can't figure out how/where it could be employed in my VB project.

Comment: You can save/load DataTable contents to XML directly using the `.WriteXML` and `ReadXML` methods. I am not sure what is gained by serializing the table

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your help again.  I was using the built-in user-scoped settings to save the `DataTable`s' values at the user-level.  And so, time and lines of code are saved by using the built-in project settings interface.  Can you point me to some example code that uses these methods in an analogous task?  I'll experiment with them today, though it doesn't really get to the bottom of what's wrong with my original solution...

Comment: Yeah, I dont know why it stopped working - `one of its dependencies` may be the key.  With non trivial apps or important settings items, I use my own `UserOptions` class so I can control where the data is saved, and tell the user where that file is should they want to migrate them to a new machine.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that would be a useful feature of using my own UserOptions.xml file (or something).  The only problem is that I'm using ClickOnce deployment for the app, and so, directing the user to the app/install directory would be a little hairy.  I'm currently trying to replace the `DataTable` user-scoped setting with a `WriteXml`-created document.  I've never used that method before, but if it does what it claims, I may be in luck.